# Variable Image Grid Display in Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have developed image grid using material ui, but all my images are displaying in fixed height..

what i want ?

i want the images to be displayed as variable height, just like unsplash.com

here is my sandbox

https://codesandbox.io/s/github/logeshhy/Bolter

Comment: what do you mean? the pictures in unsplash.com grid has fixed height (when you resize the window, the pictures stay the same height) . please elaborate on what you want to achieve